# Eclipse on Mac uses wrong JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've got two JDKs on my Mac, 1.8 and OpenJDK 11. I have this line in my .profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
```

In a terminal, java -version shows it's using 11, and echo $JAVA_HOME also points to 11.

I have set Preferences/Java/Installed JREs to 11. I have set the compliance level to 11 in the compiler config in my pom.

Eclipse, however, shows the "JRE System Library" in my project to be 1.8. When I execute a class in the project, it runs under 1.8.

What gives? Is there a secret setting on the Mac telling Eclipse to use 1.8? Or a secret setting in the Eclipse config?

(I'm using the latest version of Eclipse, 2018-09, fully up-to-date.)

**Update**: Per @vshcherbinin's comment, the Run Configuration/Java Application/JRE tab says "Project execution environment 'JavaSE-1.8' (Home)". I do not believe I have any project-specific settings. I deleted the .project, .classpath, and .settings in the project and re-imported the basic Maven project. Not sure how to make the project execution environment default to 11.

Comment: Have you looked into your Run Configuration? Check "Run Configuration" -> "Java Application" -> JRE tab.

Comment: @vshcherbinin see update

Comment: In the same "JRE" tab there is "Alternate JRE" field, you can set the JRE you want there.

Comment: @vshcherbinin Ok, that's helpful, and it does work for that one class. But it doesn't change the JRE System Library. I'd like to change the default globally.

Comment: I think you can edit your eclipse.ini to set an specific jvm to use, add the following lines before the -vmargs

`-vm

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib`

In my case I only have java 10, but it should be the same for the 11 one I think, -vm and the path should be on different lines.

Comment: [Java 11 Support for Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-11-support-eclipse-2018-09-49) is required to set the compliance level to 11. To change the system library that is used by a project do the following: in _Project > Properties...: Java Build Path_ in the tab _Libraries_ select the _JRE System Library_ node, click _Edit..._ and as _Execution Environment_ choose _JavaSE-11_.